# Javascript application as a proxy for another url tree

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a javascript application that essentially serves as a proxy for a web page located at a different location.

So if my application is running at https://my.host/my-app, it would take all subpaths and display what is at some other base location (e.g. https://other.domain/my/other/path).

So `https://my.host/my-app/index.html` will render what's at `https://other.domain/my/other/path/index.html` and `https://my.host/my-app/some/other.html` will render what's at `https://other.domain/my/other/path/some/other.html`

So its pseudocode would be:

```
function render(url, other_base_url) {
  relpath = strip_domain_from_url(url)
  new_path = join(other_base_url, relpath)

  page = fetch(new_path, authentication=my_authentication)
  return page
}
```

Why would I do this? I want to put my "wrapper" app on some hosted location and give it authentication that allows it access the application located at `other.domain`.

It shouldn't be terribly hard to do this using React and React Router but I wanted to ask if anybody had done something similar and had a simpler solution.

Comment: `I want to put my "wrapper" app on some hosted location and give it authentication that allows it access the application located at other.domain.` Bad idea. If you put your credentials in the frontend, it can/will be stolen.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this on the frontend, with React/ReactRouter? Just deploy a real HTTP reverse proxy. Any common HTTP server (Apache, Nginx) will support this use case with one or two simple lines of configuration.

Comment: @Marc Sorry, I should have clarified. The credentials aren't actually stored on the front end, they're just passed along.

Comment: @Bergi - Those are the parameters. Unfortunately I don't have the option to do anything server side so I'm looking for a front end solution.

Comment: Marc has a point. Regardless whether you "store" credentials in the browser, or whether you just "pass" them along to *any* client, it means you leaked your credentials to the public. You must not do that!

Comment: And no, a frontend solution just won't cut it. You will not only have a problem with the authentication, but also the `other.domain` will not have CORS enabled to allow embedding its content in your `my.host` app. Seriously, just get another server and install a reverse proxy on it! You don't need access to any existing server for that. (Although you probably should. Really, this sounds like an organisational problem. Put your backend team onto this task, it'll be trivial to them - far quicker than the time you even spent on this StackOverflow question).

Comment: "whether you just "pass" them along to any client, it means you leaked your credentials to the public" --

I'm curious about why this would be the case. User authenticates via something like Auth0. Credentials (aka JWT) are sent to the browser over https. They're then sent to the server via https. Server calls the authority (Auth0) to validate the credentials. Which part of this is insecure?

Comment: That's fine, but your phrasing "*I give it authentication*" was misleading. It sounded like you put *your* credentials in the wrapper app so that everyone would be able to access the application using *your* credentials. If every user uses only their own credentials, it's good.

Comment: As to the server-side solution - I understand it's much easier that way. As you correctly surmised, there's organization constraints that make that solution much harder. I'm just trying to get something done with the options that I have available to me at the moment.

Comment: Well actually if you have the option to "*put [the] "wrapper" app on some hosted location*", then you'll also have the option to use a reverse proxy there.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not. The hosted location is not a machine I can do whatever I want with. It will only run front end code.